# ACF custom field data not appearing in the front end

Tags: wordpress, acfpro

I am managing a multi-language website where the Advanced Custom Fields groups were all translated. so 5 languages = 5 field groups. I realised that the groups didn't need translating so I turned off translation for field groups.

Now I am looking at a page in the back end and the correct data is appearing in the correct field group but it is not appearing on the front end (except for in the remaining ACF field group translation). If I resave (press Update) that post then the data then appears in the front end.

I am guessing that is because an ACF has two fields, the key and the name. The backend picks up the data from the name and can only put it together with the key on save (apologies if that is not the precise explanation)

I was OK with this for the pages because there were 30 or so. I have just noticed this issue with a CPT that has 3,000 posts. What I need is some way of resaving the ACF data programatically.

I have get this far;

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'product',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
's'=> 'scorpion' // example subset with one save post,
);
$maintenance_query = new WP_Query($args);
while ($maintenance_query->have_posts()) : $maintenance_query->the_post();
  the_title();
  $fields = get_fields(get_the_ID(), );
  print_r($fields);
  echo '<br><br>';
endwhile;
```

which produces;

```
INTELSAT FLEX

Manpack – Scorpion HP

Manpack Scorpion-Lite

Scorpion™ Family

Manpack – Scorpion Multi-band X, Ku and Ka-BandArray ( [code] => 0822_5604 [partner] => Array ( [0] => 4864 ) [variations] => [resources] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [title] => The Scorpion Manpack Datasheet [type] => download [file] => http://milexia:5757/products/wp-content/uploads/sites/7/2018/02/The-Scorpion-Manpack-May-2023.pdf [internal_link] => [external_link] => ) ) [embedded_youtube__vimeo] => ...
```

The last one was manually saved after opening, the others not, so the link between the fields and the post are missing but I can see the data in place in the back end. How can I resave with the correct data.

So my question; how does get_fields **not** retrieve data that is linked with the post but will rewrite it correctly after opening in Editor and resaving?

Answer (score 0):

There was no way to template it. It turned out that ACF will display data in the back end based on `meta_key` field name eg `code` but displays in the front end based on the associated field key (of the form field_62f4a75965450).

So, in phpMyAdmin I identified the keys associated with the translations.
Using SQL of the form

```
SELECT `meta_key`, `meta_value`  FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `post_id` = 26705 AND `meta_value` LIKE '%field%'  ORDER BY `wp_postmeta`.`meta_key` ASC
```

where 26705 was the Post ID for a re-saved post displaying the meta correctly.

Then identified the keys for the translations of each field into a grid;
_code   field_62f4a76ab7c26 field_55f042831a668 field_62f4a75965374 field_62f4a75f1ec74 field_62f4a7650c39e ...

Where the first value is the correct key for the field `code`
then, for each field (I only had 9 which was a blessing)

```
UPDATE `wp0_7_postmeta` SET `meta_value` = 'field_62f4a76ab7c26' WHERE `meta_value` = 'field_55f042831a668';
```

Repeater fields use the same key for each instance

If someone would suggest an edit of the title so, should anyone need a pointer to this issue.

If anyone sees this, the moral of the story is you don't need to translate ACF field groups in a multilingual setup.